# Understanding the link between Tennenbaum Theorem and Godel Rosser

Tags: logic, model-theory, incompleteness

In Models of Peano Arithmetic by Kaye, p153, it states : Tennenbaum's theorem may be regarded as the model-theoretic analogue of the Godel-Rosser incompleteness theorem.

Similarly

In Cohen Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis, p49 it states "By a similar argument using Tarski's theorem on the un-definability of truth, (and without using recursively inseparable sets) one "easily" shows "There is no non-standard model M for the integers in which + and * are given by functions definable in Z1 (i.e. PA) and such that all the true statements of Z1 (PA) hold in M (a non standard model of Z1 (PA)).

My first question is - is there a proof of Cohens "easy" proof somewhere I could read?

My second question is on Kayes p153 statement : Is it saying that models of PA exist (viewed purely from the Metatheory) which satisfy additional statements to those that are derivable from Z1 (PA) and that these models include non-isomorphic models, called "Non-standard" models, and these additional statements are "not recursive" in that they aren't made up from a finite set of expressions based upon Z1 (PA) axioms. ? Are there examples of what these "additional statements" look like, or where they sit in the arithmetical higher-archy ? I suspect its saying more than this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid, I can not give you a satisfying answer on your first question, but I can try clear up the confusion expressed in your second question.

First of all, the theory of a model, i.e the collection of all sentences satisfied by the model, is always complete. We know, however, by the incompleteness theorem, that $PA$ is not complete. Therefore, every model of $PA$ has to satisfy statements that are not derivable from $PA$. For example, the standard model $\mathbb{N}$ satisfies $Con(PA)$ (well, presumably it does) and there is also a non-standard model of $PA$ satisfying $\neg Con(PA)$. (This is a consequence of the second incompleteness theorem. The claim that $Con(PA)$ is independent of $PA$ is equivalent to the assertion that there are models of $PA$ satisfying $Con(PA)$ and $\neg Con(PA)$.)

Secondly, Tennenbaum's theorem is not talking about the 'recursivity' of statements, but it talks about recursive (or to be more precise non recursive) models. This is, a priori, a different question. There is, however a deep connection between the two statements, as described, for example, in Kayes book (p.189) or in his article 'Tennenbaum’s Theorem for Models of Arithmetic' (2006).

Comment: Thanks Jan. So maybe I have misunderstood Tennenbaum entirely !  Looking over Kaye definition of a recursive model, its one that is isomorphic, via any isomorphism function, to a model with domain N and recursive functions of +,* (not necessarily the real +,*). So its talking about whats possible in the Metatheory, in terms of the Metatheory recursive, and so finitely defined, functions ?

Comment: Jan, also I note Kaye says (p154) that every non-standard M :  M |=PA codes some non-recursive set.  The justification for this is reference to Theorem 3.9 (simplified Godel Rosser) p38, that a recursive set of godel Numbers T is incomplete. The implication therefore is incomplete implies non-recursive.  Presumably this is because PA can derive all recursive functions, so anything it can't derive (ie the missing incomplete statements) must be non-recursive ?

Comment: Jan, So I've been wondering given the above two comments what the purpose of Tennenbaum is. As non-standard structures can be shown to exist by compactness (add a new element "c" and say its different from all elements "n" of N) - which is via an infinite number of expressions. So maybe Tennenbaum is saying there aren't any ways of creating a non-standard structure "roughly" in a finite number of steps (i.e. via some finite algorithm) ?

Comment: Every countable set can be thought of as having domain $\omega$, the standard natural numbers (just with a different labeling, ie $a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots$). So if we have a countable model of any theory, we can ask whether that model's functions/relations are computable functions and relations. Tenenbaum's theorem says that if M is a countable non-standard model of PA, then there is no algorithm which can compute addition or multiplication for that model.

Comment: Just noticed in Kaye - p189 the link between Godel-Rosser and Tennenbaum is formalised. It looks like using information related to Scott sets/Konigs Lemma + Tennenbaum implies Godel Rosser incompleteness (though I cant say I understand it yet).

Comment: @AtharAbdul-Quader, good point.  Presumably "algorithm" means a finite algorithm as opposed to no algorithm at all e.g. would use of more complex first order formulas such as those from set theory allow the +,* to be defined ?

Comment: Colin, first of all, I have to retract my claim that there is probably no deep link between Tennenbaum and Gödel Rosser. The article 'Tennenbaum’s Theorem for Models of Arithmetic' by Kaye proves that the theorems are, in a precise sense, two versions of the same result. The proof is, however not trivial. Apart from that, I would like to point out, that your understanding of the term recursive seems to me a bit off. First of all, a single statement can not be not recursive. Only infinite collections of statements can be non-recursive.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't know what you mean, when you write that you can not compute a infinite model in a finite number of steps. No infinite model can be computed in a finite number of steps. Also, every algorithm is finite by definition. In general, your questions seem very confused. Perhaps you should recap the basics of recursion theory again.

Comment: Jan, Thanks, your point about Tennenbaum applying to recursive structures as opposed to recursive expressions/sets of expressions  was enough to put me on the right road on the question posted. I thought a single statement could be, in effect, non-recursive if what it refers to isn't (e.g. a statement of a Truth function is non-recursive).  I also thought whether an algorithm is viewed as finite depends on how its being interpreted and the branch of maths (e.g. infinitary logic allows inifinitely long statements) ?

Comment: Jan, if you edit your answer to include the link between Tennenbaum and Godel Rosser I can then accept it as the response to my second question.

Comment: Hello Colin. I can not guarantee that no infinite algorithms are never considered in any branch of mathematics. I have never seen any infinite algorithm and you can be safe to assume that algorithms are finite if not state otherwise. Observe that a (countable) infinite algorithm can decide any problem on the natural numbers, or any countable set, just by an infinite case distinction. The same idea shows that a finite set of formulas can never be non-recursive.